# How to use Truncated Multivariate Normal distribution in Julia

Tags: julia

I am running an (Markov Chain Monte Carlo) MCMC in Julia where one of the steps requires that I simulate from a Truncated Multivariate Normal Distribution(TMvN).

Right now, I call the package TruncatedNormal from R using RCall.

The Distributions package in Julia offers the Truncated options but only seems to work for ivariate distributions.

Is there a native Julia package I can use to directly simulate from a TMvN?

Comment: Looks like this is [an open issue at Distributions.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distributions.jl/issues/480).